# Tkinter python quit/exit crash

Tags: python, crash, tkinter, exit, quit

Im making a GUI and want to add an exit button to close the window. The only problem is, when i add a button with the following code:

`root = Tk()`

`Exit = Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.quit()).grid(row = 6, column = 1)`

the GUI window crashes. Im running windows 7 and Python 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
root = Tk()

Exit = Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.quit).grid(row = 6, column = 1)
```

in the root.quit() I took out the parenthesis. See if that solves the problem

Comment: @user1956027: I think you must be mistaken. This definitely is the problem with the code in your question. If the same thing happened then there is more code you aren't showing us. Most likely you replicated the problem elsewhere, such as creating a menu.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, here is a pastbin for a bit more of the code. Its the only part that I would think would cause a problem, everything before is just imports and functions ect. http://pastebin.com/jpL04jFz

Comment: without more code I don't see anything in there that would crash the program except possibly quit() as mentioned before

Comment: @Joseph Owens Have a look at that link I posted, it has some more code that may have the reason it crashes, though im not sure my self.

Comment: @user1956027 Yes, I posted that comment after reviewing the code in the link.

Comment: @JosephOwens I suppose I could post all the code, but like I said, I dont really see how that would affect anything. Anyway, here is everything: http://pastebin.com/3CEYuDpc

Comment: @user1956027 The quit button didn't work for me with it as Quit(). When I changed it to quit() the gui crashed. When I changed it to quit with no parenthesis it works as it is supposed to. I am running windows 7 with python 3.3. There may be something going on with python 3.2, but other than that I don't have any guesses, if anyone else knows what's going on they can explain in more detail. Good luck!

Comment: @JosephOwens Thanks for giving it a try, I will see if changing to 3.3 helps anything.